# PHP Class inside class inside class

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I know this is similar to my last question [PHP Static vs Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263322/php-static-vs-instance)

But I didn't want to add it there and confuse that question, I believe it does stand on its own merits as a question

I have three classes `Billing Invoice InvoiceItem`

The billing class works out the billing and finishes up with the data for the invoice and and array of data from the invoice items `$billing` and `$billingItems`

the questions is how do I call the methods needed

In Billing Class

```
$invoice = new Invoice();
$invoice->createFomBilling($billing, $billingItems);
```

Do I:

1.

In Invoice Class

```
public function createFomBilling($billing, $billingItems)
{
    foreach($billingItems as $billingItem)
    {
        $item = new InvoiceItems();
        $item->setDataFromBilling($billingItem);
    }
 }
```

In InvoiceItem Class

```
public function setDataFromBilling($billingItem)
{
    $this->item1 = $billingItem->item1;
    $this->item2 = $billingItem->item2;
    $this->item3 = $billingItem->item3;
    $this->item4 = $billingItem->item4;
    $this->item5 = $billingItem->item5;
    $this->save();
 }
```

OR

2.

In Invoice Class

```
public function createFomBilling($billing, $billingItems)
{
    foreach($billingItems as $billingItem)
    {
        $item = new InvoiceItems();
        $item->item1 = $billingItem->item1;
        $item->item2 = $billingItem->item2;
        $item->item3 = $billingItem->item3;
        $item->item4 = $billingItem->item4;
        $item->item5 = $billingItem->item5;
        $item->save();
    }
 }
```

this way i do it all in the invoice class and i dont write code in the invoiceItem class

Any ideas

Comment: hahhaaha....i am confused whether you are giving an answer or asking a question :-p

Comment: lol, sorry, i am asking a question, I really just asking if i should keep the code in the calss that i am using i.e. invoice in Invoice and invoiceItems in InvoiceItems and put all methods there

Comment: Try to write methods with within classes.